Wix remove registry key when something is uninstalled
I have an ExePackage defined to install SQL Server 2022 and uninstall it, when someone reruns the installer to perform an update. How do I associate the RemoveRegistryKey action to the uninstallation of SQL  Server?
This is how the package is defined:
<util:RegistrySearch 
          Id="Sql2022InstanceFound" 
          Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\160" Variable="Sql2022InstanceFound"
          Result="exists" Win64="yes"/>

<PackageGroup Id="SQL2022Express">
      <ExePackage Id="SQL2022Express"
              DisplayName="SQL Server 2022 Express"
              Cache="yes"
              Compressed="no"
              PerMachine="yes"
              Permanent="no"
              Vital="yes"
              DetectCondition="Sql2022InstanceFound"
              InstallCondition="INSTALLSQL=1"
              Name="Redist\SQLEXPR_x64_!(loc.LANG).exe"
              SourceFile="$(var.DependencyFolder)\SQLEXPR_x64_!(loc.LANG).exe"
              InstallCommand="/ACTION=Install /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS [SQLQUIET] /HIDECONSOLE /FEATURES=SQLEngine /UpdateEnabled=0 /INSTANCENAME=PHARMSPEC /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=Builtin\Administrators /SQLSVCACCOUNT=&quot;NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE&quot; /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=[SAPASSWORD] /NPENABLED=1 /TCPENABLED=1 /SKIPRULES=RebootRequiredCheck"
              UninstallCommand="/Action=Uninstall /INSTANCENAME=PHARMSPEC /FEATURES=SQL /QS /HIDECONSOLE">
        <ExitCode Value ="3010" Behavior="forceReboot" />
    </ExePackage>
</PackageGroup>

Now I would like to remove the registry key Sql2022InstanceFound when SQL Server 2022 is uninstalled. I defined a RemoveRegistryKey component as follows. How do I associate the component Database_Uninstall with SQL Server? Please help.
<Component Id="Database_Uninstall" Guid="9EE7E965-415F-4AF9-B13C-0205DEA3A0CD" 
    Feature="DefaultFeature" Win64="yes">
    <RemoveRegistryKey Root="HKCU" Action="removeOnUninstall" 
           Key="Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\160" />
</Component>

